# How to predict binary values for time series models?

Tags: time-series, data-science-model

How one can predict 100 new binary values (0s and 1s) if there are 3200 previous values?

Note that there is no seasonality, but just a set of numbers. I used Arima, lgbm, Markova but it predicts randomly (about 50 percent accuracy), lstm gives all zeros.

Comment: Are you sure you can do better than random?

Comment: I don`t know. The task is set, it is necessary to give the maximum possible result of accuracy